# How to run VPython on Mac offline

Tags: python, vpython

I don't have much experience with Python. Don't judge me for that.  I just beg you to tell me how to take use of VPython. I already have Python installed on Mac. *Version 3.9.8*. At least I believe to know. It's something called IDLE Shell. Apparently I can run normal Python code there. But I didn't found any source telling me how to access on packages like VPython. Is it possible at all in the shell? Tutorials where that package is used I only see on online editors like Trinket or GlowScript itself. Normally access is granted by typing
*GlowScript 2.6 VPython* and afterwards the specific code follows. However in the shell it gives error *invalid syntax*. So does another trick exists?

**Edit** I have installed VPython via Terminal: *pip install VPython*.

Comment: Have you tried importing your installed vpython like this: `from vpython import *`?

Comment: Thanks, that's the basic trick! I also had to reinstall VPython correctly via */usr/local/bin/python3.9 -m pip install vpython* but after including your winning line, I'm now able to run VPython code. Strangely the simulation opens in browser, but whatever

Comment: The "strangeness" about the display being in a browser is due to the fact that VPython uses the WebGLl 3D renderer that is built into browsers.